# R Shiny: resizing the entire app by 50% as if you're doing it on the browser

Tags: css, r, shiny

My app looks just right when I launch it in Chrome and click zoom out to 50% of the original size. How can I make the app do that automatically when launched? I tried to reduce the font size to 50%, but that wouldn't do the job, since other elements, such as plots and check boxes are still the same.

Comment: Seems like mostly a CSS question with no code to go on. Can you give a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your css:
html{font-size: 15 }

//you have to adjust font size as you like